# Will , going to , or something else and why?

Tags: tense

Should i say

> Are you sure you **will play** the next match ?

Or

> Are you sure you **are playing** the next match ?

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are correct and both of them ask essentially the same question.  There is, however, a very subtle difference between these two sentences that could influence me to prefer one over the other in different situations.

Simple future is often used for **statements of intent**. So your first choice is more natural if your are asking whether the person is sure that they *intend* to play.  For example:

> It looks like you twisted your ankle badly in the last match.  Are you sure you will play the next match?

There is reason to believe that the player's *intent* may have changed, so you can use simple future to ask about the new state of their intent.

On the other hand, present progressive often refers to **fixed plans** to do something. So the second choice would be more natural if I'm asking about plans that have already been made. For example:

> I thought that your match had been scheduled for tomorrow. Are you sure that you are playing the next match?

Here the question is about the state of the *fixed plans* for the next match. This time it's less about what the player *intends* to do and more about what the *plan* is for what they will do.

Again, this difference is very subtle. In many cases your two sentences are going to be interchangeable.